# Methods and overriding extended classes

Tags: java, oop, overriding

If you write a class that you intend for others to extend but have ONE method that you don't want overridden by those subclasses, how could you do this?

Comment: You mean to disallow overriding?

Comment: Yes, I do. @mad_manny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `final` modifier to a method, class, or variable means it can't be extended or changed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html